# Android increase log cat's log messages

Tags: android, json, cordova, logcat

I was wondering if it's possible and where would you go to increase the character limit of a single log message for LogCat. I am trying to dump some data stored locally on my android device (as a JSON string), however the string is quite large and gets cut off in log cat.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't.  Either break it into multiple lines, or write it to a file instead of the system log.

Comment: Do you know if there's a default write to file function in cordova?

Comment: you can use the org.apache.cordova.file plugin to write to files